# Python CDLL load library with different dependency QT version

Tags: python, qt, ctypes

I'm using python 2.7 with :

- PySide 1.2.2
- Ctypes

I'm loading dll from a business partners with CTypes that using a different version of Qt than me. So I get this error :

```
Exception: [Error 127] Specified function not found
```

My loading code is simple :

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "win") + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
self.path = ctypes.util.find_library("my.dll")
self.libext = ctypes.CDLL(self.path)
```

The path generated is good and

I don't see what choices I have to load such external dll. I don't want to change my graphic lib, because I could get same conflict with an other partner library that could use the same lib.

How can I handle that ?

- Is There a way to load dll with his own dependency ?
- Is it possible to use different version of Qt in same thread ?

Comment: Can you modify my.dll to embed a manifest as resource ID 2?

Comment: No I can't, external lib is certified by governement and is providing by other company. I don't have permission to modify it.

Comment: I manage to run 2 qt versions by using subprocess.call(["python ", 'SubProcessRequest.py", my-params). But this solutions requires I install python and provides clear scripts on target machine. This is not acceptable solution. Do you know if there is a solution to run method in safe dependencies thread ?